# How to avoid zero value in column after minus 2 dates in sql?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this query:

```
SELECT CREAD, DATE, NOTIFICATION,
NVL (ROUND ((((:endate - :stdate) * 24) - CASE 
WHEN MAX(CREAD) = MIN(CREAD) THEN MAX(CREAD)
ELSE MAX(CREAD) - MIN(CREAD)
END) / COUNT(NOTIFICATION),2),0) "MTTR"
FROM DUAL;
```

When user select dates between start_date and end_date then execute this table:

```
 CREAD     DATE       NOTIFICATION     MTTR
  123      1/1/2017        6            56
  1000     30/1/2017       3            80
```

When user select no dates between start_date and end_date then execute this table:

```
  CREAD     DATE       NOTIFICATION     MTTR
  123      1/1/2017        6             0
  1000     30/1/2017       3             0
```

IN "MTTR" column value is 0. but i want same value in the above table.

How to write query in oracle sql?

Answer (score 1):

> When user select no dates between start_date and end_date then ... "MTTR" column value is 0.

When the user selects no date the first part of the expression `(:endate - :stdate)` evaluates to `(null - null)`, hence the rest of the expression evaluates to `null` and therefore your query returns the `NVL()` default of `0`.

> but i want same value in the above table.

To get this outcome you need to handle null values for `start_date` and `end_date`. Maybe this will work for you:

```
nvl(:endate -:stdate, 1)
```

Or you may want some other default. But as the value of `MTTR` depends on the range of `start_date` and `end_date` it's hard to see how you can get *"the same value"* when the user enters no bounds.

Comment: @AmmadWasim - sorry I had a stray parenthesis. Corrected now

Comment: or i should use sysdate?

Comment: I don't know. You see, this is your application, your data, your business rules. I can suggest an approach which you can use to derive a correct answer but only you can determine which values to plug in. If you still want further help you must some sample raw data including expected output for different values of `:endate` and `:stdate` ,  including when the user gives no input at all. An explanation of the business logic for deriving MTTR would help too.